# CPU maxing out in Live

Tags: c#, multithreading, iis

Our live site has recently started maxing out the CPU for a reason I've not yet been able to diagnose. We ran Microsoft's Debug Diagnostic tool when revealed the 2 threads using most the CPU were:

```
System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr,  
  System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef)

System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods
```

Can anyone suggest any possible causes? The site itself is MVC5 in C# hosted on a Windows 2008 R2 Server running IIS7.5. I realise this isn't a lot to go on. If you need to anything specific, I'll do my best to find it.

Thanks

Comment: I'm sure that these threads are managed, so you can examine their stacktrace. I think that you can find a lot of interesting there :)

Comment: Take a look here: http://improve.dk/how-to-identify-which-request-caused-a-runaway-thread-using-windbg/